# Install a theme in local machine. Should I need the FTP data connection?

Tags: wordpress

I have just installed wordpress at my localhost for the first time.

I want to install a theme, and it asks me about my FTP username and password.

It says this: "To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should **contact your web host**."

I'm wondering if wp is usually directly installed in the production web server or if it could be installed first in a local machine... What should I do?

Answer (score 10):

Add this to your wp-config.php

`define('FS_METHOD','direct');`

Due to Linux having such a more restrictive file system, this will enable to you write directly to the folder.

This will solve that ftp problem while installing a new plugin or theme.

Answer (score 2):

On OSX, I used the following, and it worked:

```
sudo chown -R _www:_www {path to wordpress folder}
```

_www is the user that PHP runs under on the Mac. *(You can change this to whatever your PHP install runs under on your specific OS)*

*(You may also need to chmod some folders too. I had done that first and it didn't fix it. It wasn't until I did the chown command that it worked, so I'm not sure if it was the chown command alone, or a combination of chmod and chown.)*

Comment: This did it for me. I'm wondering now why MAMP doesn't make this a standard setting. I suppose some people serve from their computers tho and this would make things riskier? Either way it was a perfect work right out of the box.

Comment: This worked for me installing a WordPress multisite on Mac OS High Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

If WordPress asking hostname and connection details for installing plugin and themes, we need to add a function hook in the wp-config.php file in the home directory.

`define('FS_METHOD','direct');`

for more details refer the page.
https://support.cloudways.com/how-to-resolve-wordpress-asking-for-ftp-credentials-error/

Comment: please refer to this page also
https://girishvasmp.wordpress.com/2015/10/31/wordpress-only-displaying-homepage/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using your local machine as the install location, instead of using the in-app installer (which is now askign you for ftp details), fire up a browser and download the theme directly from the [Theme Directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/), unzip it into the themes folder at wp-content/themes/name-of-theme. You can then activate the theme from the admin panels.

See also the instructions at http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes.