# wordpress asks for ftp password while installing plugins

Tags: wordpress, apache, ftp, centos

I have a centos with user anamika with ftp loging.

I create wordpress folder loging with user anamika in webroot directory. User anamika has apache as primary group. The create folder gets user of anmika:apache when create.

When I try to install plugin it asks for ftp login.

When I changes user from anamika:apache to apache:anamika it works fine.

Please suggest a way to solve this user issue.

I checked following suggestion and wordpress blogs but didn't worked.
[Wordpress plugins it asks for FTP Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880396/wordpress-plugins-it-asks-for-ftp-details)
[Wordpress asking for my FTP credentials to install plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922644/wordpress-asking-for-my-ftp-credentials-to-install-plugins)
[Installing plugin for wordpress website hosted locally is asking for ftp details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933305/installing-plugin-for-wordpress-website-hosted-locally-is-asking-for-ftp-details)

Answer (score 1):

If WordPress asking hostname and connection details for installing plugin and themes, we need to add a function hook in the wp-config.php file in the home directory.

define('FS_METHOD','direct');

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233152/install-a-theme-in-local-machine-should-i-need-the-ftp-data-connection/27754477#27754477

Comment: it's a way when web server permissions are set well. If not adding hook wouldn't work. Best solution would be set plugins and upload directory permission properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Paste the following code to your wp-config.php file,
preferably just below every other line of code to install plugin without ftp details...

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

Comment: Gaurav Jariwala, Thank You for your suggestion. What I am searching for a way to add user to group apache and work without adding codes to wp-config.php files. I tried addring user to group apache but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the permission of the user apache. I changed the user and group of the apache in httpd.conf file to the ftp user and it solved the issue.
Changed User apache Group apache to User anamika Group anamika